# How to properly check if a slow starting java tomcat application is running so you can restart it?

Tags: service, daemon

I want to implement a automatic service restarting for several tomcat applications, applications that do take a lot of time to start, even over 10 minutes.

Mainly the test would check if the application is responding on HTTP with a valid response.

Still, this is not the problem, the problem is how to prevent this uptime check to fail while the service is under maintenance, scheduled or not.

I don't want for this service to be started if it was stopped manually, with `service appname stop".

I considered creating `.maintenance` files on stop or restart actions of the daemon and checking for them before triggering an automated restart.

So far the only problem that I wasn't able to properly solve was, how to detect that the app finished starting up and remove the `.maintenance` file, so the automatic restart would work properly.

Note, an init.d script is not supposed to wait, so the daemon should start a background command that solves this problem.

Comment: Is the .maintenance written by a servlet running on the server?
Does the long-running startup occur in an init() method of a servlet?

Comment: Ignore the reasons why this application is slow. You can assume that you have zero control over the application you are running. In my case I am trying to improve the uptime of Jira or Confluence which, from time to time can crash, but crashing in an ugly way where there only way to detect is by checking if they are still responding on HTTP requests.

Comment: OK, so it's not your own app that you have additional control over it. You might try a model somewhat like JBoss deployment... you create control files (like .maintenance) that store the state _you_ think it should be in:  x.starting, x.running, x.stopped. So you have different checks depending on state (nothing while "stopped"). While starting, you're looking for it to be running within a certain time limit or you restart. While running, you expect a ping kind of service to respond. It's a nuisance, and subject to long startup issues, but you have limits with another's product.